# Listener for the Gallery content change

Tags: android

I am developing one application in that app i have created one service that get all the images from sdcard and it's metadata and stored into database.

So now i want to delete and add database content if images are added in gallery and deleted from the gallery so Is there any listener we can get if any image add/edit/delete from Gallery application?

Comment: You can use Android file Observer. It won't be the beat solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could count the number of images

```
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/images");
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    int numberOfImages=files.length;
```

to see if any photo was added or deleted.

Update me too when you find how to find if a photo was edited.

Comment: Thanks for the anwer, but how can i know that particular image was deleted ?

Comment: Are you displaying the images on gallery from database or from local storage?